# Losing all money in US Bank?

Tags: united-states, banking, international-transfer

I am a foreign national working in the US on a Visa. I will be visiting my home country this December, and transferring over to an H1-B Visa while there. The visa has been approved but I need to get it stamped at the US Embassy in my home country.

Now I have been working in the US for a couple of years now and have a fair amount of money (a few tens of thousands of dollars )saved up in my (Checking) bank account in the US. I also have a 401k with my employer.

Although highly unlikely, if the embassy refuses to stamp my visa I could be stuck outside the US with all my money in a bank account here. With no way to visit the bank in person, I am afraid I could lose all my life-earnings! What would be the best course of action to take assuming for generality these two scenarios:

a ) What would be the best actions to take before leaving to ensure that if I am unable to return, I can transfer my money out of the US?

b ) Assume that I take no action before leaving and then am unable to return to the US, what would my options be to access my money while outside the US?

Answer (score 5):

Online banking, including international wire transfers, works from (nearly) anywhere in the world; make sure to have it set up.

You can also give someone *power of attorney* (authorization to act in your name, the bank must accept him as you), if you have someone you trust enough; or if not, give a lawyer power of attorney. You can do that even after the fact, while you are out of the country; you would work with an international lawyer company.

Answer (score 0):

You can remotely close the account and transfer the money out to your account in home country.

If you have netbanking you can also setup remittance service to your country